# Tealium IQ: overriding utag_data values within the dev google chrome console?

Tags: javascript, tealium

Hi the stackoverflow community,

Being newbie in Javascript, i would like to know if there is a way to do like a 'datalayer.push' function or equivalent with the Tealium's datalayer to override the values implemented by my dev into the website's datalayer.

**Can you please provide some code example of how you will do it ?**

My idea is to do 2 things:

- to show the dev what is the expected value for a specific variable directly 'live' even if i don't have any access to the CMS ==> like an overriding of the value for the variable
- to get the possibility to trigger some tags or some events (e.g via the tealium IQ extensions) directly from the dev  google chrome console

I was able to do it previously with Google analytics with some websites which were using Google tag manager.

Because i don't have access to the CMS, i should only use the Google dev console

Many thanks for your help

Sébastien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tealium support's team provide me the answer.

You should use your console & rewrite the datalayer

// example of rewriting the datalayer driectly within the google debugger dev ==> 'console' tab

utag_data = {"site_region":"test_test","site_currency":"EUR","page_name":"Tealium test","page_type":"test_test","tealium_event":"page_view","country_name":"France_test","country_code":"FR_test"};
rewriting the datalayer with utag_data.jpg

[image: rewriting the tealium's datalayer]

But if you like to keep it accross your session & when you"re refreshing the page; you need to enable

"persistent" + "enable local Overrides"

As a result you will be able to acess to the utag.js script in editing environnement on which you changing the tealium's datalayer and values.

After, you can refresh the pages and the values will be keeping the new values you defined for the datalayer's variables.

Hope my comments can help the community,

Regards, Sébastien